# Unexpected result when joining a table in a year range

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I'm working with an `users`, `user_roles` and `point_standards`. Users need to achieve a certain points in a certain period based on which role they have. Points are retrieved from courses which are done in a specific year. Retrieving the user points is not the problem.

For the certain points a user has to achieve, a criteria is defined. These are made for 3 years and can not overlap. See the example below.

[image]

This means, from 2018 to 2020, the user with the role that is assigned to these criterias needs to achieve 93 points.

In 2018, the user should achieve 31 points (93 / 3).

The problem is when the user wants to check the criteria for years corresponding to more criteria. Lets say the user wants to check the criteria in the years 2018, 2017 and 2016. This means:

> ```
> (93 / 3) + (50 / 3) + (50 / 3)
> ```

When ceiling these sums, this should result into a criteria of 65 points for 2018, 2017 and 2016.

For my expected end result, I want to get an overview with all users and the criterias for specific years.

In the example below, I'm trying to retrieve the criteria for a single user for the years 2018, 2017 and 2016.

```
SELECT `users`.first_name,
        ps.points

FROM `users`
       # Join the user roles table
       INNER JOIN `user_roles`
         ON `users`.`role_id` = `user_roles`.`id`

       # Get the criteria for 2018, 2017 and 2016
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, role_id, COALESCE(points / 3) AS points
                  FROM point_standards
                  WHERE 2018 BETWEEN YEAR(start_year) AND YEAR(end_year)
                     OR 2017 BETWEEN YEAR(start_year) AND YEAR(end_year)
                     OR 2016 BETWEEN YEAR(start_year) AND YEAR(end_year)) ps
         ON (user_roles.id = ps.role_id)

WHERE users.id = 123
GROUP BY `users`.`id`, ps.id
ORDER BY `points_internal` DESC
```

This results in 2 rows with the correct criteria.

[image]

**Expected result**

In this case, it should return 3 rows. This because of I want to see the criteria of the years 2018, 2017 and 2016.

I then hoped I could sum the `points` of these 3 rows for each user.

**Questions**

- Why is it only returning 2 rows instead of 3? I've selecte 3 years to look in.
- How can I sum these amount of rows together so I can get an overview of all users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not selecting 3 rows, you are selecting all rows that include at least one of 2016, 2017, 2018 and there are precisely two of those rows (the first two in your table).

If you want separate rows for each of the three cases, you can write a subquery for each case and perform a `UNION ALL` on them. So instead of writing

```
SELECT id, role_id, COALESCE(points / 3) AS points
FROM point_standards
WHERE 2018 BETWEEN YEAR(start_year) AND YEAR(end_year)
    OR 2017 BETWEEN YEAR(start_year) AND YEAR(end_year)
    OR 2016 BETWEEN YEAR(start_year) AND YEAR(end_year)
```

you use

```
SELECT id, role_id, COALESCE(points / 3) AS points
FROM point_standards
WHERE 2018 BETWEEN YEAR(start_year) AND YEAR(end_year)
UNION ALL
SELECT id, role_id, COALESCE(points / 3) AS points
FROM point_standards
WHERE 2017 BETWEEN YEAR(start_year) AND YEAR(end_year)
UNION ALL
SELECT id, role_id, COALESCE(points / 3) AS points
FROM point_standards
WHERE 2016 BETWEEN YEAR(start_year) AND YEAR(end_year)
```

If you have a table from which you source the years, you can perform a join with that table instead, which is a bit less verbose.

*Edit:* Whole query should look like this then:

```
SELECT `users`.first_name,
        ps.points

FROM `users`
    # Join the user roles table
    INNER JOIN `user_roles`
        ON `users`.`role_id` = `user_roles`.`id`

    # Get the criteria for 2018, 2017 and 2016
    LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT id, role_id, COALESCE(points / 3) AS points
            FROM point_standards
            WHERE 2018 BETWEEN YEAR(start_year) AND YEAR(end_year)
            UNION ALL
            SELECT id, role_id, COALESCE(points / 3) AS points
            FROM point_standards
            WHERE 2017 BETWEEN YEAR(start_year) AND YEAR(end_year)
            UNION ALL
            SELECT id, role_id, COALESCE(points / 3) AS points
            FROM point_standards
            WHERE 2016 BETWEEN YEAR(start_year) AND YEAR(end_year)
            ) ps
        ON (user_roles.id = ps.role_id)

WHERE users.id = 123
GROUP BY `users`.`id`, ps.id
ORDER BY `points_internal` DESC
```

Or a bit shorter (by creating your own `years` subquery):

```
SELECT `users`.first_name,
        ps.points

FROM `users`
    # Join the user roles table
    INNER JOIN `user_roles`
        ON `users`.`role_id` = `user_roles`.`id`

    # Get the criteria for 2018, 2017 and 2016
    LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT id, role_id, COALESCE(points / 3) AS points
            FROM point_standards
            JOIN (SELECT 2016 AS y UNION SELECT 2017 AS y UNION SELECT 2018 AS y) years
            ON years.y BETWEEN YEAR(start_year) AND YEAR(end_year)
            ) ps
        ON (user_roles.id = ps.role_id)

WHERE users.id = 123
GROUP BY `users`.`id`, ps.id
ORDER BY `points_internal` DESC
```

Comment: Do I need a different `LEFT JOIN` for each case then?

Comment: No, just left join with the entire block, i.e., replace the subquery.

Comment: It's giving me this error: `[42000][1055] Expression #4 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'ps.criteria' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Comment: Also, will I still be able to sum these 3 rows together for each user?

Comment: Sure, just replace `ps.points` in the select list with `sum(ps.points)` and remove `ps.id` from the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: This gives me the result of `4439.000046` and also an incorrect amount of current user points... how did this happen?

Comment: Hard to say without looking at your data. Run the query without aggregation of ps.points first, that should give you a better idea of what's happening.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183292/discussion-between-bas-and-henning-koehler).